# Identifying two unopened bags with earth-toned pieces

Tags: set-identification

I have two bags that I need some help identifying what set they are from. I bought a mixed lot without books and seem to be a few different sets so far. Would love some assistance with these two please.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The first bag can only be from [76208 The Goat Boat](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=76208-1):
[image: The Goat Boat]

Since the piece [18910 Panel 3 x 4 x 3 Curved with Double Clip Hinge](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18910&idColor=69) has only ever appeared in Dark Tan color in this single set.

[image]

The [Dark Tan Door, Frame 1 x 4 x 6 with 2 Holes on Top and Bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60596&idColor=69) only reinforces this.

[image]

But the second bag is from a different set, found by [searching for the parts](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=26601&itemSeq1=2&colorID1=&itemNo2=75937&itemSeq2=1&colorID2=&itemNo3=30552&itemSeq3=5&colorID3=&in=S)

- Wedge, Plate 2 x 2 Cut Corner (at least 2) [image]
- Plate, Modified 2 x 2 with Bar Frame Octagonal, Reinforced, Completely Round Studs [image]
- Hinge Cylinder 1 x 2 Locking with 1 Finger and Axle Hole on Ends with Slots (at least 5) [image]

This search gives two results, but the presence of the minifigure [Tobias Beckett](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?M=sw0941), specifically the back of his jacket [image] confirms it as [75215 Cloud-Rider Swoop Bikes](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75215-1)

[image]

Comment: Absolutely is! Thank you! Appreciate your help

Comment: @Legofan You're certainly welcome! Feel free to take the [tour] and read the [help] to learn [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) :)